# Controlling Custom Page To Show After Specific Tasks

Tags: inno-setup, task, custom-pages

After couple of hours googling and struggling, and got no where, I decide to ask for help here.

What I am trying to accomplish, I am trying to get the IP from the user and use it as a command line parameter in my [Run] Section.

So I have this:

```
[Task]
Name: "License"; Description: "Usb Key License Driver"; GroupDescription: "UsbLicense"; Flags: checkedonce
Name: "License/Desktop"; Description: "Desktop License"; GroupDescription: "UsbLicense"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "License/NetworkClient"; Description: "Network Client License Key"; GroupDescription: "UsbLicense"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
```

Now if the user chooses Network client, I want to be able to show a custom page, and get the IP and use it like this:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\Drivers\Program.exe"; Parameters: "/ip:{code:GetIPhere}"; StatusMsg: "Installing drivers..."; Tasks: License/NetworkClient
```

I managed to create my own page and ran this:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  CustomForm_CreatePage(wpSelectDir);
end;
```

Now for my main question:

1) How do i control WHEN the custom form shows, it shows up before it activates before my Task page.

2) If i can get it to show AFTER task page? How do I write code to make it show under the "Client Network" condition only from task. (If i do this in NextButtonClick method, how do i know what is the page id of my custom page?)

Thanks for all you help, i am just geting so close to finishing my installer, but this is driving me nuts.

**----EDITED----**

I sovled my problem 1, there is a pageAfter parameter when creating the custom page, and we can use the selectedTask constant to determine it to appear AFTER the Task page:

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Form_CreatePage(wpSelectTasks);
end;
```

Thanks and Regards,
Kev84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Pascal Script WizardSelectedTasks, which will return you the string of tasks you have created, just do a "Pos" on the returned string and you'll be able to determine if your specific task was chosen.

```
[code]
function Form_ShouldSkipPage(Page: TWizardPage): Boolean;
var
 selectedTask : string;
 skipPage : bool;
begin
  skipPage := true;
  selectedTask := WizardSelectedTasks(false);

  if (Pos('client', selectedTask) > 0) then
  begin    
    skipPage := false;
  end;
  Result := skipPage;

end;
```